# Volume button is disabled in video while showing in chrome using HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome

I want to play a `.mkv` format video in chrome using html, but audio button is shown as disabled like in below image  -

[image]

HTML code -

```
<html>
<video controls height="100%" width="100%" 
 src="myvideo.mkv" 
 autoplay muted="false" type="video/mkv">
</video>
</html>
```

I am not able to listen audio. Draging and droping video in chrome browser is also having the same problem.

Comment: With what codec is encoded your audio source in this mkv?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check it in mac os

Answer (score 0):

You should remove muted property from your tag

```
<video controls height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="video.MKV" 
    autoplay type="video/mkv">
</video>
```

Comment: It works for me :(
did you try to change the video with another one?

Comment: other's are running fine.

Comment: Good!, it looks like your video got a problem with encoding as mentioned in comments, try to covert it using format factory or download it again from the internet.